# Send xml string in json object using php slim

Tags: php, json, xml, slim

I have written a REST Api using slim framework 3, and returning response in JSON like this,

```
return $response->withHeader(
        'Content-type',
        'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    )->withJson($data, 200);
```

which is working fine.

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><dialog createdBy=""createDate=""><dialog>' // looks like this

$data = [
    'name' => 'xmlName',
    'xml'  => $xml // fetching from db
]
```

Now, I have xml string stored in database and want to send it to the client end, I have to save that xml string as in another database as it is.

But when I encode xml string, my json gets break.

I have also tried like,

```
json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_TAG);
```

which converts my xml to.

```
"\u003C?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?\u003E\n\u003Cdialog createdBy=\"\"
```

How can I correctly encode the xml in JSON and then get back the original xml string as it is?

Your feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `withJson()` source code you'll see that all it does with data is processing it with `json_encode()`—nothing special on the Slim side. In fact, **your XML is just fine**: `\u003C` and `\u003E` are the entities for `<` and `>`. Remember that JSON is a data format for computers, not people!

Additionally, the [JSON spec](http://json.org/) states that you need to have a top level object or array. So you can't just send a string back to the client and expect it to be processed as JSON because it will not be JSON. If `json_encode()` does not just crash it's because it has been designed to encode partial JSON since it's a useful feature some times. You absolutely need to design a valid JSON structure, e.g.:

```
->withJson(array($xml), 200)
```

Comment: Actually I was encoding an array, xml string exists in that array.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just found my answer by the hint of htmlentities @Álvaro González gave. 
I just converted my xml string like,

```
[
    'name' => 'xmlName',
    'xml'  => htmlentities($xml) 
]
```

I am able to receive the xml string as it is without any json break.

Comment: `htmlentities()` will just corrupt your XML (or at least force the receiving side to undo the encoding). Why do you think you need it?

Comment: Its working fine i think, If I pass $xml as it is, my json gets break. That's why I used htmlentities(). So that my json didn't get break and I don't have to undo it. I have receive the exact same string.

Comment: You must be doing something else you haven't said (such as displaying the XML in a browser or processing data with some library). This site is meant to be a collective knowledge base and whoever googles here will get the wrong impression that `json_encode()` is broken or incomplete, which is certainly not the case.

Comment: @Álvaro González, as I said in my question, I had to fetch a row from one database table containing a column having xml data, and save it to another database using a webservice. When I post my webservice using a  RestAPI client, it returns me broken json. I was simply returning the response as I mentioned above using slim. When I manually converted my xml string with htmlentities(), then it worked fine and I received fine json. I simple decode that json and saved it to another database table which was my problem.